# app_message_outbox_send is not in app space

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am working on a Pebble watch face and I ran into a problem, the function app_message_outbox_send seems to throw an error (which then crashes my app). The error is "[INFO    ] E call_internal.c:36 syscall failure! 0..0x8 is not in app space."

The relevant code:

```
static void askPhoneForCharge(){
    if(bluetooth_connection_service_peek()){
        DictionaryIterator *iter;
        app_message_outbox_begin(&iter);
        dict_write_uint8(iter, KEY_PHONE_ASK, 0);
        app_message_outbox_send();
    }else{
        phoneCharging = 0;
        phoneCharge = 0;
        updatePhoneBattery();
    }
}
```

Here is how I set up the handlers and open the channel:

```
app_message_register_inbox_received(inboxReceivedCallback);
app_message_register_inbox_dropped(inboxDroppedCallback);
app_message_register_outbox_failed(outboxFailedCallback);
app_message_register_outbox_sent(outboxSentCallback);
app_message_open(app_message_inbox_size_maximum(), app_message_outbox_size_maximum());
```

Comment: Could you include your full logs? Why do you think it happens on the call to `outbox_send()`? Can you add some debugging messages around too? Ideally, post a link to the full source code so we can look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem while sending the app_message_outbox_send() command which was getting called by to the Up_button_click handler.
The following initialization code in the Init() method fixed it for me.
Look at the "Register message handlers" & "Init buffers"

```
void out_sent_handler(DictionaryIterator *sent, void *context){}
static void out_fail_handler(DictionaryIterator *failed, AppMessageResult reason, void* context){}

static void in_received_handler(DictionaryIterator *iter, void* context){}

void in_drop_handler(AppMessageResult reason, void *context){}

static void init() {
// Register message handlers
  app_message_register_outbox_sent(out_sent_handler);
  app_message_register_inbox_received(in_received_handler);
  app_message_register_inbox_dropped(in_drop_handler);
  app_message_register_outbox_failed(out_fail_handler);

  // Init buffers
  app_message_open(64, 64);
  // Create main Window element and assign to pointer
  s_main_window = window_create();



  // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
  window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });
  // Show the Window on the watch, with animated=true
  window_stack_push(s_main_window, true);
}
```

Comment: could share your full c source file here?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, you can not use the message functions while in the initialization phase, so I started a timer that only executes once to take care of the initial messaging.